# 100% iPhone app crashes on using voice dictation in iPad mini

Tags: iphone, ipad, crash, voice, dictation

The following steps always make app crashes.

1. install 'iPhone app' from app store to my 'iPad Mini' (except for univeral app)
2. find any text field on the app and start using it (then keyboard pops up)
3. touch 'voice dictation' button on the keyboard

I guess this is iOS bug on iPad mini.
Does anyone suffered with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it crash on a full-size iPad?

Comment: No, it only occurs on iPad 'Mini'.

Comment: yes, I've found this bug two, the stack show the problem lies in [UIDictationMeterView -initWithFrame:]

Comment: Has this been fixed by Apple in one of the recent iOS 6 updates? I don't have an iPad mini to test on but the app I develop was also logging crashes due to this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after updating my iPad mini to the latest iOS version (as of this writing, version 6.1.2), using the voice command on an iPhone app installed on the mini doesn't cause the app to crash.